# Which partitions do I need to convert Windows 10 installation into VM?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-image

**What I would like advice with:** I have A PC that had previously dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. I have instead decided to use my Linux install as my main system and run Windows virtually from it on the same device.

**What I have done:** To start with I simply used Ubuntu to create disk images of my Windows partitions with the intent to restore them as a virtual machine. Ubuntu saved each of them in its preferred .img format. Now that I have installed VirtualBox the options are to either to burn the disk images back to a physical drive and use the .vmdk format to boot virtually that way or convert the .img format to .dvi and spin up a wholly virtual disk. The latter conversion is a built-in feature of VirtualBox that I have tested and seems to work. `VBoxManage convertdd efi.img EFI.vdi`

**What I should know going forward:** Something that does not get mentioned in any of the Q&As I have read is the fact Windows 10 comes with four partitions (the main system "C:drive", the reserved partition, the recovery partition, and the efi boot partition). I created a separate disk image for each one of these for thoroughness but I don't know if this is necessary or if the C:drive is all that is required for the VM. How would one even load multiple .dvi images at once? notwithstanding the fact that the efi bootloader was already configured to dual-boot Ubuntu, (so having two bootloaders = 2×hairpulling)

**Stumbling through weeds:** Just this clarification is all I need in the near-term to save time, however, any further advice is welcome since this will likely prove an arduous task later on, like considering whether it is okay to keep the .dvi on the same partition as my Linux install or whether or not Windows will still activate.

Comment: Windows 10 native has 3 partitions:  EFI, Recovery, and Main Data.  I have a Windows 10 VM here (built from a Windows 10 ISO) and it has the same 3 partitions.

Comment: Did you create your VM from an ISO of a running system or was that an installer?  What software are you using?  I have disk image for each partition that I can convert into a separate .vdi. Can I run all of them at once or do I have to combine them into a single .vdi with multiple partitions?  How are you getting away with not needing the "Windows reserved" partition.

Comment: I just installed Windows and it made the partitions.

Comment: That's helpful to know, but I am trying to restore disk images from windows that was already installed, not start with a new installation.  Any advice on how to do that on VirtualBox?